# Call JavaScript function from resource file in Camel

Tags: javascript, apache-camel

I have a javascript file myscript.js that contains the following method:

```
function getName(){
  return "Paul Simon"
}
```

Now, I want to call this method from my route. I was expecting that using the resource construct I could load the script in one instruction and call the method in a subsequent one. something similar to:

```
from("restlet:/Bookmarkee/boolean/v3?restletMethods=POST&restletBinding=#restletBinding")
            .routeId("/Bookmarkee/boolean/v3?restletMethods=POST")
            .to("language:javascript:resource:file:/C:/Users/max777/AppData/Local/Temp/7009839156674102420/myscript.js")
            .to("language:javascript:getName()").to("mock:result");
```

However, this is not working. I keep getting:

> Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "getName" is not defined. (#1)

What am I doing wrong?

I can see camel saying in the logs that it found the file:

> Reading resource: file:/C:/Users/max777/AppData/Local/Temp/8119222516029335972/myscript.js into the content cache
>   Using resource: file:/C:/Users/max777/AppData/Local/Temp/8119222516029335972/myscript.js from the content cache
>   The script evaluation result is: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction@707d7290

And so, I fail to understand what is the semantic difference between the following two endpoints. Syntactically, I only removed the word "resource" in the second one:

```
to("language:javascript:resource:file:/C:/Users/max777/AppData/Local/Temp/7009839156674102420/myscript.js")
to("language:javascript:file:/C:/Users/max777/AppData/Local/Temp/7009839156674102420/myscript.js")
```

Comment: Is myscript.js in the classpath?

Comment: I edit the post to answer your question. I can see in the log that the script is loaded, cached, and evaluated. And yes, the only function it contains is getName().

Comment: Never done this so I'm guessing here. Try to use getName like this <langauge langauge="javaScript">in.body.getName</langauge>

Comment: I tried request.body.getName,  body.getName, request.body.getNameNOnExistent, body.getNameNonExistent: they all evaluate and return null. No error. in.body.getName produces a script compilation error. The variable in is not defined.  Really desperate here.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the JavaScript `myscript.js` to the classpath (in my case this is the `scripts` directory) and change it so that `getName` is invoked:

```
function getName(){
    return "Nirvana"
}

getName();
```

Following routes worked for me:

```
public void configure() {

    // using the javaScript method
    from("direct:start1")
        .setHeader("myHeader")
        .javaScript("resource:classpath:scripts/myscript.js")
        .log("start1: header = ${header.myHeader}");

    // using the language tag
    from("direct:start2")
        .setHeader("myHeader")
        .language("javascript", "resource:classpath:scripts/myscript.js")
        .log("start3: header = ${header.myHeader}");

    // hack alert: transform=true replaces the body which later is read in the simple method
    from("direct:start3")
        .to("language:javascript:classpath:scripts/myscript.js?transform=true")
        .setHeader("myHeader")
        .simple("${body}")
        .log("start2: header = ${header.myHeader}");

}
```

Instead of reading the file from the `classpath`, `file`, or `http` could be used.

**EDIT**

In Camel 2.10.X, you could use `classpath:scripts/myscript.js`. For Camel versions >= 2.11.X, you must use `resource:classpath:scripts/myscript.js`.